# Deploy VS2013 SSIS packages to SQL Server 2012 & edit in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, ssis, versioning, bids

I'm afraid I know the answer to this already, but I'm hoping someone can point me in a better direction. I just finished developing a large ETL project using VS2013. My dev machine has SQL Server 2012 installed, and everything works perfectly executing from within VS. However, I just went to deploy the project to another device running SQL Server 2012, and got a version error.

I thought if I could open the solution in VS2012, the packages might recompile correctly. However, I can't open them in VS2012 due to version errors again ("version can't be lower than current version" error). I'm pissed because everything worked fine in development with the VS2013/SQL2012 combo, but now suddenly it's no good?!?

Can someone please help me figure out how to get these packages downgraded to work with VS2012/SQL2012? There are only a few script tasks involved if that makes a difference. Mostly it's just basic SSIS tasks and data flows.

Thanks.

Comment: can you try to edit your solution file, open your solution file in notepad and try to change the version

Answer (score 5):

I found a workaround how you can "downgrade" your SSIS 2014 packages to SSIS 2012. I wrote it on my blog here:

http://vaniecastro.com/2015/02/26/how-to-downgrade-sql-server-integration-services-2014-packages-to-2012/

The idea is that you need to manually modify the XML file, change the PackageFormatVersion and replace ExecutableType property and componentClassID attribute values to use the DTSX2 Version 2012/01 values instead of the DTSX2 Version 2014/01 ones.

Comment: This is ugly, but it can get the job done. Shame on MS for this compatibility snafu though.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using Visual Studio 2015 SSDT Preview. This now allows you to choose which version of SQL Server you want to target, including SQL Server 2012. I successfully downgraded my packages from VS 2013 / SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2012 this way.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383.aspx

Once the shell is installed, go to the Project menu=>Project Properties=>Configuration Properties=>TargetServerVersion and choose 2012.